# Get individual type by OWL API - Java

Tags: java, owl, ontology

I've connected my Java application to Ontology using OWL API, connection and retrieving classes worked very well.

Now, I'm trying to get the class, to which an individual belongs.

```
OWLNamedIndividual ind = factory.getOWLNamedIndividual(":myIndTest", pm);
```

I'm trying to find the class of an individual (inputted from user) , and then perform my action.

How can I get the class (direct class) for this individual?

Thanks in advance, Regards

Answer (score 0):

After some research in the OWL API docs, I've tried :

```
System.out.println("Class:  " + ind.getTypes(ontology).toString());
```

and it works.

Including, the individual is available in one class only, and cant be found in more than one.

Regards